# how to test grpc endpoints reply?

Tags: testing, grpc

I create prisma records through grpc endpoints, but in tests the results I get

```
        Want: "message:\"[{id:rJDWRx text:kamil44, published:false}]\""
        Got: "message:\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"rJDWRx\\\",\\\"text\\\":\\\"kamil44\\\",\\\"published\\\":false}\""
```

gist https://gist.github.com/Shibbaz/2a9f6897bb0f701c99b11fb2e3d99d70

I expect to run test succesfully

Answer (score 0):

It's challenging to repro without access to the service.

Have a look at this: https://go.dev/play/p/ijNCH9lsTbu

I *think* your `CommentsReply.Message` is a `string` and it appears to contain a JSON-encoded string (the `got` in your example).

So, in the code below, I've defined `Message` as a distinct type that gets `JSON.Marshal`'d before being used as the `string` value in `CommentsReply.Message`.

Make sense?

Your code was further escaping the strings (`\"`) by its use of `%q`. In this example, '%s' is used instead and it avoids this (double escaping).

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type CommentsReply struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

type Message struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    Text    string `json:"text"`
    Publish bool   `json:"publish"`
}

func main() {
    CommentId := "rJDWRx"

    message := Message{
        ID:   CommentId,
        Text: "Kamilsd",
    }

    jsonMessage, err := json.Marshal(message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    commentsreply := CommentsReply{
        Message: string(jsonMessage),
    }

    want, err := json.Marshal(commentsreply)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Want: %s\n", want)
}
```

Yields:

```
Want: {"message":"{\"id\":\"rJDWRx\",\"text\":\"Kamilsd\",\"publish\":false}"}
```

Your code would be simplier if you clarified the `got` and `want` values. Instead of:

```golang
if tt.expected.out.Message != "[{ID:"+CommentId+" Text:Kamilsd}]" {
  t.Errorf("Out -> \nWant: %q\nGot: %q", tt.expected.out, comment)
}
```

You could have:

```golang
want := tt.expected.out.Message
got := comment

if want != got {
  t.Errorf("Out -> \nWant: %q\nGot: %q", want, got)
}
```

One other minor point, you should consider `t.Fatal` (!?) in your test:

```golang
if err != nil {
  t.Fatal(err)
}
```